# winforms report generator for pdf output

Tags: winforms, reporting, pdf-generation

Need to generate some financial report where the formatting is controlled by the data

haven't done reporting in a while but does any reporting support that

e.g. based on a flag in the source dataset
the row text could be bold
the row could have an underlining
the report could start a new group header etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a component called the ReportViewer for WinForms which ships with Visual Studio.  This will do exactly what you need.  You can bind it to one or more DataTables and it will essentially render you a report in PDF or in XLS or what have you.  If you don't need to present it to the user, just use the [LocalReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport%28VS.80%29.aspx) class and call its Render() method.

Comment: Yeah, that's no problem.  You define the formatting on RDL format using ms's report designer.  It even allows you to data-define your formats.  And if you want more customization than that, RDL is just XML, so it's fairly easy to emit your own report design of need be.